# error while initializing int type flexible array in structure in c

Tags: c

i am trying to use flexible array for int variable.

Below is my code:

```
struct S2 {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    int stud_roll[];
}s2g;

void test(){
        s2g.stud_roll = {0};
}

int main(){
        test();
        return 0;
}
```

But its not working.

How can fix the problem? what is my error?

Comment: I believe your struct needs to be allocated through `malloc` and allocate extra space for the struct to hold the length of the flexible array.

Comment: You use the compiler time initialization for dynamic sized array.
When you want to initialize this array, the you have to allocate memory, and fill them.

Sorry, it not that easy

Comment: And you can't assign arrays, whether they are flexible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use your struct with a Flexible Array Member (FAM) you need a pointer to struct, not type struct. The FAM provides the convenience of allowing allocation for the struct and the FAM in a single allocation, rather than needing to allocate for the struct and then for `stud_roll` separately. For example:

```
struct S2 {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    int stud_roll[];
} *s2g;   /* note the declaration as a pointer */

void test (void)
{
    s2g = malloc (sizeof *s2g + ELEMENTS * sizeof *s2g->stud_roll);
    if (!s2g) {
        perror ("malloc-s2g");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
```

There you allocate storage for both the struct `sizeof *s2g` plus the element of `stud_roll`, e.g. `ELEMENTS * sizeof *s2g->stud_roll`. This provides the single allocation/single free.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ELEMENTS 10

struct S2 {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    int stud_roll[];
} *s2g;

void test (void)
{
    s2g = malloc (sizeof *s2g + ELEMENTS * sizeof *s2g->stud_roll);
    if (!s2g) {
        perror ("malloc-s2g");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    s2g->foo = 1;
    s2g->bar = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
        s2g->stud_roll[i] = i + 1;
}

int main (void) {

    test();

    printf ("s2g->foo: %d\ns2g->bar: %d\n", s2g->foo, s2g->bar);
    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
        printf (" %d", s2g->stud_roll[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
    free (s2g);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** since the flexible array member is `static`, you cannot have an *array of struct* containing a flexible array member -- but you can have an array of pointers with separate allocation for each)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/famtst
s2g->foo: 1
s2g->bar: 2
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `(struct S2).stud_roll`. Without any memory you will write out of bounds. Assimung there is no padding `sizeof(struct S2) == sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)` - there is no memory allocated for stud_roll cause the member takes no memory "by itself".

`s2g.stud_roll = {0};`

You can't assign arrays in that way in C.

You can use compound literal to allocate some memory on stack:

```
#define STUD_ROLL_SIZE  4

struct S2 * const s2g = (void*)((char[sizeof(struct S2) + STUD_ROLL_SIZE * sizeof(int)]){ 0 });

void test(void) {
    s2g->stud_roll[0] = 1;
    // or
    memcpy(s2g->stud_roll, (int[]){ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 4 * sizeof(int));
}
```

or use malloc to dynamically allocate the memory, you need to allocate more memory than the `sizeof(struct S2)`:

```
struct S2 *s2g = NULL;

void test(void) {
    s2g = malloc(sizeof(struct S2) + STUD_ROLL_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    if (s2g == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Abort ship! Abort ship!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    s2g->stud_roll[0] = 1;
    free(s2g);
}
```